# How do I format text from file in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, split, hex

I am starting java lessons and my first task is to format the text from a file in Java. I did some research but I just could not find the answer on the internet.
I have a css file with multiple rows and I have to format the content of it. What I managed to do so far was read the content to the console and the output looks like this :

```
.fa-vimeo:before { content: "\f27d"; }
.fa-black-tie:before {content: "\f27e";}
.fa-fonticons:before { content: "\f280";}
```

Now I just want to format it, so that it will look like this:

```
VIMEO(62077) // the number in quotes is hexadecimal and I want to convert it to decimal
```

This is what I tried

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
 class CreateCssEnum
 {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
 {
  FileReader fr = new FileReader("D:\\eclipse\\font-awesome.css");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

String line = null;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
     StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(line, "-:\"\" ");
      String a = tok.nextToken();
      String b = tok.nextToken();

    System.out.println(a.toUpperCase() + b);
}
br.close();
}

}
```

-->I edited the code as I recieved help to improve it

But now I receive the error :

```
"Exception in thread "main" .FAglass
 CONTENT\f000
java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(Unknown Source)
at CreateCssEnum.main(CreateCssEnum.java:16)"
```

Many thanks.

Comment: That error sounds like you're missing an `import` statement.  If you press Ctrl-Shift-O in Eclipse, it adds any missing `import` statements to the top of your file.

Comment: Btw, when you're done, you might want to post your code on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ :)

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for StringTokenizer is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/StringTokenizer.html).
It says it is part of the `java.util` package. So you need to import that. Either just import StringTokenizer:

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
```

Or import everything from java.util.

```
 import java.util.*;
```

You also have an error with the string `"-:"" "` , I don't know what you want to do there, but this is not a valid string literal in Java. Perhaps you need to escape the inner quotes, `"-:\"\" "`.

(Since you're using Eclipse, you can mark the line with the error, hit CTRL+1, and it'll suggest fixes for your errors, or CTRL+SHIFT+o to add imports that are missing)

Comment: Wow, thanks nos, i imported the package and I only get one error now Syntax error on token "" "", delete this token. But i need to pup the qoutes as characters so the code will know where to substract my string from

Comment: You don't double-up double quotes to escape them.  Just use a backslash to escape the double quote.  You want `"-:\" "`

Answer (score 0):

You have to import `StringTkenizer` before using it. Place this line at the top of you file, just after `package` declaration:

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
```

Another problem is that you're creating `StringTokenizer` **outside** the while loop.

At that point, line always has null value (the while loop only ends when line == null).

You have to process each line **inside** the while loop, just after reading the line.

By the way, instead of using `StringTokenizer` you can use the method `split()` that every String object has by default.

Take a look [String.split (java.lang.String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

Comment: you are righht, that is why i cannot call the string. I was defining it as null. I will update my code

Comment: Yes. I noticed you also need to put an import. I've updated my answer

Comment: Although I recommend you to use split instead of StringTokenizer